# как правильно расположить на сервере бэк и фронт?

Tags: php, сервер, хостинг, backend

Я хочу написать REST api на PHP для фронтовой части моего сайта. [image: расположение фронтовой части]

для этого я создал папку API на хостинге в которой планирую разместить PHP код. Это правильное решение?
Как сделать это верно?

Comment: верно разместить там один php-файл,  весь код вынести за пределы корня сайта

Comment: А какая, простите, разница, как будет называться папка, в которой вы планируете разместить PHP код?